# Getting dynamically created behaviorID with find() in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using a ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender inside a repeater in a aspx page.
Since I need to have a unique behaviorID, I am setting it in this way:

```
((CollapsiblePanelExtender)(e.Item.FindControl("ControlPanelExtender"))).BehaviorID =
        "bhvControlExtenderPanel" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
```

Now in Javascript I have to collapse/expand all the created panels according to a certain logic, but I am struggling in performing a partial match using the find() function.

```
$find("bhvControlExtenderPanel0").collapsePanel();
```

works, but I have to do it for every Panel, and I don't know the exact number.
Basically I need the equivalent of:

```
$("[id$='bhvControlExtenderPanel']")
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[Attribute Starts With](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector:

```
$("[id^='bhvControlExtenderPanel']")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but $find is short for .Net's findComponent() function. This is not a standard JavaScript function and is specific to Microsoft's Ajax JavaScript library. $find returns javascript object, and a javascript object normally don't have a method called collapsepanel()